# how to write unit tests for recaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, recaptcha

In my express js application, I have a route which is protected with [google repatcha v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-recaptcha). Code provided below for reference.
Can you help me to write unit tests for this route using mocha (or any other framework)

```js
app.use('/register', VerifyRecaptcha, Registeruser);
```

Comment: For tests you bypass recaptchas.

Comment: @RolandStarke, But I want to test reacaptcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to test captcha, since this is 3rd party code specially built for preventing forms to be automated with bots (which your test is actually is). Fighting with captcha won't give you stable and quick test, since captcha algorithms can be changed without any notifications, and your solution will stop work.

If you really want to work with captcha in tests or some crawlers, you can connect to special API service, and pay per each solved captcha, like https://anti-captcha.com/mainpage . But this costs money and super-slow

You can disable captcha for tests or mock some responses from captcha service (positive\negative)